# Calculate the sum of this series: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2 3^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 3^n}
$$
I tried to use the regular way to calculate the sum of a power series $(x=1/3)$ to solve it but in the end I get to an integral I can't calculate.

Thanks

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 3^n}. \tag 1
> $$

Write

> $$
> S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\exp( x n)}{n^2}. \tag 2
> $$

So we get

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 3^n} = S(-\ln(a)). \tag 3
> $$

Note that

> $$
> \frac{d^2 S}{dx^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp( x n)
> = \frac{\exp(x)}{1 - \exp(x)}. \tag 4
> $$

Then

> $$
> S(x) = \int dx \int dx \frac{\exp(x)}{1 - \exp(x)}
> = - \int dx \ln(1 - \exp(x))
> = \operatorname{Li}_2( \exp(x) ). \tag 5
> $$

Thus

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\exp( x n)}{n^2}
> = \operatorname{Li}_2( \exp(x) ). \tag 6
> $$

Put in $x = -\ln(3)$ and we get

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] {
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 3^n} = \operatorname{Li}_2(1/3).} \tag 7
> $$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you get to an integral of $\frac{ln(1-x)}{x}$.

This cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary function. In fact, the sum is the series definition of a special function called "dilogarithm" which belongs to the family of "polylogarithms".
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}=Li_2(x)
$$
The integral definition of dilogarithm is :
$$
Li_2(x)=-\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt
$$
In case of $x=1/3$ :
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 3^n}=Li_2(1/3)=0.366213...
$$
For the meaning and the use of special functions, for example see :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpecialFunction.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html

A more general paper :

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: May I ask how the constants of integration disappear during the manipulation (as shown in my answer)?

Comment: They don't really disappear, but they can be $=0$ while computing them in setting $x=0$.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{aligned} I \ := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n^2} & \implies \dfrac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n} \\ & \implies x \dfrac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{n}}{n} \\  & \implies \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left( x \dfrac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}x} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1} = \dfrac{1}{1-x} \\ & \implies x \dfrac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}x} = \int \dfrac{1}{1-x} \text{ d}x  \\ & \implies x \dfrac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}x} = \log \left( \dfrac{1}{1-x} \right) \\ & \implies I = \int \dfrac{1}{x} \ \log \left( \dfrac{1}{1-x} \right) \text{ d}x \ = \mathrm{Li}_2 (x) \end{aligned} $$

> $$ \therefore \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2 3^n} \ := \ \mathrm{Li}_2 \left( \dfrac{1}{3} \right) $$

Comment: I cannot understand why someone downnoted your answer which seems correct. May be because your integrals are undefined ?

Comment: May I ask what you mean by undefined? Is it to do with the constant of integration? (Also, it seems as though I have a serial downvoter. They've been going through a lot of my posts.)

Comment: By "undefined integral", I mean "integral without the bounds".

Comment: Oh, thank you. Yea, I wasn't too sure of dealing with the constants of integration, but knew that evaluating the equalities at certain values of $x$ would lead to the constants vanishing.

Comment: @JJacquelin, indefinite is the word you were looking for. (: